# Iterate an keyless array inside another keyless array in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, api

I have an API that look like this :

```
[
    [
        1,
        "__Default__"
    ],
    [
        7,
        "parent 1"
    ],
    [
        9,
        "parent 2"
    ],
    [
        17,
        "Parent 3"
    ],
    [
        18,
        "Parent 4"
    ]
]
```

Now Im trying to iterate the value of all this list and populate it into a select2, but I'm having trouble iterating the second level list.

below is my code :

```
var all_parent_json = $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "/api/content_parent/"+ project_data.id +"/?format=json",
                dataType: "application/json",
                async: false
            }).responseText;
            var all_parent = JSON.parse(all_parent_json);

            var parent_option_list = [];
            for (var x in all_parent){
                for (y in all_parent[x]){
                    //THIS IS WRONG
                    console.log(all_parent[x].[y])
                    console.log(y)
                parent_option_list.push({"id": all_parent[x].[0], "text": all_parent[x].[1]})
                }
            }
```

Any help is much appreciated thanks.

Comment: It's only really wrong because you are iterating an array with `for( .. in .. )`, there are multiple iteration tools for arrays like map and reduce. Also, stay away from sync http requests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`Array.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to your ease.

```
var parent_option_list = JSON.parse(all_parent_json).map(m => { return {id: m[0], text: m[1]}; });
```

Comment: Thanks @Thirueswaran, just what i needed

Answer (score 2):

change all_parent[a].[b] to all_parent[a][b]

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what the . is for between your indexing. I think that the code you are trying to produce is like this:

```
for (x in all_parent) {
    for (y in all_parent[x]){ 
        console.log(all_parent[x][y]) }}
```

The periods in between [x] and [y] are a syntax error. So, I think you want to build your list like this:

```
parent_option_list.push({"id": all_parent[x][0], "text": all_parent[x][1]})
```